Prove that there exists a group $G$ of order 24 that is non-abelian and has a faithful two-dimensional complex representation.
Prove that there exists a group $G$ of order 24 that is non-abelian and has a faithful two-dimensional complex representation. Prove that this group is not isomorphic to $S_4$.

So far I have had the following progress:
(1) Let $\phi: Q_8 \rightarrow GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ be the representation of $\mathbb{Q}_{8}$ given by:
$\phi(i) = I = \begin{bmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{bmatrix}$,
$\phi(j) = J = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$,
$\phi(i^m j^n) = I^m J^n \quad \text{for all } m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$
(2) Let $w$ be the quaternion defined by $w=\frac{1}{2}(-1+i+j+k)$, then  $w^3=1$ and the conjugation by $w$ stabilizes the quaternion group $\{\pm1, \pm i, \pm j, \pm k\}$. In this way, we can think of the semidirect product $Q_{8}\rtimes Z_{3}$, with:
$$(x, m)\bullet(y, n) = (x\varphi_{m}(y), m+n)$$,
with $\varphi_k(x) = w^{k}xw^{-k}$, for all $k \in \{0,1,2\}$ and $x \in Q_{8}$.
but I don't know how to extend the given representation to the semidirect product, or if that idea works.

The quaternion group is denoted by $Q_8$, while the field of $p$-adic number sis denoted by $\Bbb Q_p$. So I would not mix up these notations. You are using both $Q_8,\Bbb Q_8$ in $(1)$. A dihedral group has faithful 2-dimensional irreducible representation, so this would work. For $S_4$ it doesn't work over $\Bbb R$, see this post.

Thank you very much for your help @DietrichBurde . You are absolutely right, that is one solution. I would also like to know if the idea I have proposed is useful for building a representation.

That is, I want to know if the representation can be built using the semidirect product.

The construction you give already gives the two-dimensional complex representation you want:
Your approach is to try to construct a subgroup of the non-zero quaternions of order $24$, starting with the group $Q_8$ of order $8$, and extending to a group of order $24$ by noting that conjugation by $w= \frac{1}{2}(-1+i+j+k)$ has order $3$ cycles $i,j$ and $k$ and so normalizes $Q_8$. But then the resulting semidirect product is already realized as a finite subgroup of the group of quaterions of norm $1$ (as the subgroup generated by $\{\pm 1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}\cup \{\frac{1}{2}(-1 +i+j+k)\}$). But the quaternions $\mathbb U = \{q \in \mathbb N: q \bar{q} = 1\}$ of norm $1$ act on $\mathbb H$ by left multiplication, and if you identify $\mathbb H = \mathbb C\oplus \mathbb Cj \cong \mathbb C^2$ this becomes a two dimensional complex representation of $\mathbb U$ which restricts to $G$ to give a two-dimensional of the group 24-element group $G$.
